# MongoDB(py) - How to retreive data, modify it, update it?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, discord, bots

This is for MongoDB using python for a discord bot.
I wanted to know how can I get a certain value from an ID, then I want to then modify that value and update it.

//Here I set up the Database and Collection

```
db = client.mymongodatabase #Database
mycol= db.mymongocollection #Collection in Database
```

//Here I make the entry into the Mongo Database Collection

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  setupbank = ({"_id":(str(member)), "coinA":100, "coinB":50,"coinC":50,"coinD":50})
  mycol.insert_one(setupbank)
```

//The Problem. I have a function that generates 4 random integers, one per coin type. But how can I retrieve the coin data and add the random earnings to the existing values, and finally update the entry in the mongodb collection?

```
@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx):
  coinAearn= random.randint(1,100)
  coinBearn= random.randint(1,100)
  coinCearn= random.randint(1,100)
  coinDearn= random.randint(1,100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used mongodb for many of my discord bot projects, the easiest way to do this is using $set, and .update_one() function. If you have any problems after this, don't hesitate to reply back!

```py
@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx):
  ({"_id":(str(member)), "coinA":100, "coinB":50,"coinC":50,"coinD":50})
  user = mycol.find_one({'_id': ctx.message.author.id}) # we find the user we want, in this case the author of the cmd
  coinA = user["coinA"] # Here we store each individual coin in variables
  coinB = user["coinB"] 
  coinC = user["coinC"] 
  coinD = user["coinD"]

  coinAearn= random.randint(1,100) + coinA # add their current coin value
  coinBearn= random.randint(1,100) + coinB
  coinCearn= random.randint(1,100) + coinC
  coinDearn= random.randint(1,100) + coinD
  mycol.update_one({'_id': user}, {'$set': {'coinA': coinAearn}}) #update each coin with the new earnings
  mycol.update_one({'_id': user}, {'$set': {'coinB': coinBearn}}) #We use the $set to set the new value, 'coinB' to coinBearn.
  mycol.update_one({'_id': user}, {'$set': {'coinC': coinCearn}})
  mycol.update_one({'_id': user}, {'$set': {'coinD': coinDearn}})
```

Note: this is not the most optimal way of doing it, you can shorten it a lot more but I left that as a quest for yourself..

Another tip I have is when you register a new user, use member.id to store their "_id" value.